# Combobox selection events

Tags: c#, wpf

Good day. I making some programs in Windows forms, and now start to investigate new beautiful world of WPF. The first problem i face that WPF combobox working other way. My C# code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void comboMenu_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (comboMenu.Text == "Meat soup")
        {
            textPrice.Text = "2.5";
            textDescription.Text = "Tasty and hearty soup with pieces of beaf and pork";
        }
        if (comboMenu.Text == "Vegetable soup")
        {
            textPrice.Text = "1.5";
            textDescription.Text = "Light and healthy soup with pieces of potato";
        }
        if (comboMenu.Text == "Chicken roll")
        {
            textPrice.Text = "3.5";
            textDescription.Text = "Fresh vegetables with pieces of chiken";
        }
    }
}
```

And XAML code like this:

```
ComboBox x:Name="comboMenu" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" SelectionChanged="comboMenu_SelectionChanged">

        <ComboBoxItem Content="Meat soup"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Vegetable soup"></ComboBoxItem>
        <ComboBoxItem Content="Chicken roll"></ComboBoxItem>
    </ComboBox>
```

Here the problem. Combobox ignores first selected value at all and dont change any text in textboxes. Than when i select second time something, textboxes get confused and the menu choice dont apply to description. I feel that its something in XAML code need to change. Please help.

Comment: Please be careful when selecting tags, so you don't select the C language tag instead of C# (as you've done). I've fixed it for you now, but please pay more attention in the future.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Sorry for that, well noted. Will double check next time

Comment: Wpf is great, i far prefer it to winforms. Pretty much everyone uses binding with it though. It's not just winforms with a few things changed, it's quite different and you're best advised to embrace it's strengths. https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/30564.wpf-uneventful-mvvm.aspx#Select_From_List_IndexChanged

Comment: @Andy its looks nice, but now as for me WPF is very moody thing. Like now when i use advice below from ASh and everything must working, my XAML code send me error "name Food dont exist". I already find the solution in another topic, so i must to do some manipulations with folder deleting and rebuilding project. Im new guy in the world of programming and may be complaining a lot, but first time face the problem which must be solve outside the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF allows to focus on data without much manipulations with UI elements.

Declare a class which hold information about menu items:

```
public class Food
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { gt; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
}
```

fill menu combobox with menu items:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="comboMenu" DisplayMemberPath="Name" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="26,30,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1">
    <local:Food Name="Meat soup" Price="2.5" Description="Tasty and hearty soup with pieces of beaf and pork"/>
    <local:Food Name="Vegetable soup" Price="1.5" Description="Light and healthy soup with pieces of potato"/>
</ComboBox>
```

use Bindings to SelectedItem instead of selection event to update information about current selection:

```
<TextBlock Name="textPrice" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Price, ElementName=comboMenu}"/>

<TextBlock Name="textDescription" Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Description, ElementName=comboMenu}"/>
```

Comment: thank you, but SelectedItem property dont appears in TextBlock XAML code. What i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Do not check `comboMenu.Text`, but `comboMenu.SelectedItem`, which is a ComboBoxItem in your case:

```
var selectedItem = (ComboBoxItem)comboMenu.SelectedItem;
var selectedText = (string)selectedItem.Content;
```

---

If you set

```
<ComboBox SelectedValuePath="Content" ...>
```

you can also use the SelectedValue property:

```
var selectedText = (string)comboMenu.SelectedValue;
```

---

With the XAML namespace dclaration

```
xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
```

you can also use `string` items instead of ComboBoxItem

```
<ComboBox ...>
    <sys:String>Meat soup</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Vegetable soup</sys:String>
    <sys:String>Chicken roll</sys:String>
</ComboBox>
```

where you now get a SelectedItem that is string:

```
var selectedText = (string)comboMenu.SelectedItem;
```

---

You may also use a `switch` statement instead of multiple `if` statements:

```
switch (selectedText)
{
    case "Meat soup":
        textPrice.Text = "2.5";
        textDescription.Text = "Tasty and hearty soup with pieces of beaf and pork";
        break;
    case "Vegetable soup":
        textPrice.Text = "1.5";
        textDescription.Text = "Light and healthy soup with pieces of potato";
        break;
    case "Chicken roll":
        textPrice.Text = "3.5";
        textDescription.Text = "Fresh vegetables with pieces of chiken";
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem like ASh said, but XAML in my case looks little different.

```
<TextBlock Name="textPrice" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboMenu}" Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>

<TextBlock Name="textDescription" DataContext="{Binding SelectedItem, ElementName=comboMenu}" Text="{Binding Path=Description}"/>
```

In case its is useful for somebody.